# install ionic 2 error : npm ERROR cannot read property 'path' of null with windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic2

i have problem when install ionic 2 with windows 10. i have installed npm LST version and type

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

but get an error

> npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null

what a problem, i also do `npm cache clean` also not working.

Comment: which npm version are you using? [github error link](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15348)

Comment: node : v6.9.4 and npm : 4.0.5 LTS version in nodejs website ...what a problem @suraj?

Comment: there seems to be a bug with npm..you checked the link? maybe try to re install or install different version of npm

Comment: i have download node js previous version : node-v4.7.2-x64.msi, and installed it, this is weird, node -v was correct 4.7.2 , but npm -v was still `4.05`. i also download several files previous version, and installed many times. but  npm -v is still `4.05`.

Comment: according to https://nodejs.org/en/download/ LTS node includes 3.10 npm.. do a clean uninstall and then try

Comment: yes i have success install previous version node and npm, but i get another eror`npm ERR! Invalid protocol: null`, i don't use proxy by the way...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have problems with installation of packages due to errors related to paths, I just go directly to the folder where node_modules is installed and delete it manually.

In your case, look for the ionic and cordova folders in `C:\Users\juand\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.

Delete them and run `ionic -v` and `cordova -v` to make sure that you get the message "'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Now you can run `npm i -g ionic cordova` again and it will start the process from scratch and you will never see that error message again.

This happens because when packages get updated, the folder structure may have changed, hence the old path won't work. Cheers